# R.string.value Help android notification

Tags: android, int, charsequence

whats the deal with

```
 CharSequence contentTitle = R.string.value;
```

Error cannot convert from int to CharSequence. Is there a way around this or am i missing something?
i tried

```
String s = R.string.value + "";
CharSequence contentTitle = s;
```

it returns integers values.
Any help?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`R.string.value` is a call to the static field in the class R, which is auto generated by Eclipse and which does a kind of summary of all your resources. To retrieve the string, you need to use :

```
CharSequence contentTitle = getString(R.string.value);
```

If you open the R class you will see that it contains only numbers that are references to the compiled resources of your project.

Comment: @Sephy I'm having an issue with getString(), I keep getting "The method getString(int) is undefined..." what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do try getting with this method?

Comment: @Sephy I'm just trying to retrieve the actual value stored in strings.xml

Comment: This is quite weird, I can't answer you just like that, I would need to see your code. Maybe you are doing something wrong. Do you know that this method is either associated to a context instance OR a Resource instance. So, maybe this is your issue.

Comment: Perhaps this would help solve he problem? =>   context.getString(R.string.value)

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was suggesting. Thank you for the precision

Comment: You could also try getResources().getString(R.string.value)

Answer (score 7):

To retrieve the string, you need to use getString(),

but getString() is a method from Context class.
If you want to use this method outside your Activity class, you should get link to your context first and then call:

```
String s = mContext.getString(R.string.somestring)
```

Answer (score 1):

R.string.value returns the reference ID number of the resource 'value'.  If you look at your R class it will appear as something like this:

```
public static final class string {
  public static final int value=0x7f040007;
}
```

I've been experiencing issues with referencing the getString() method.  The exact error that Eclipse spits at me is:

> The method getString(int) is undefined for the type DatabaseHelper.MainDatabaseHelper

After reading for awhile I've figured out that you must reference your application's context to get access to the getString() method.  I was trying to create a private SQLDatabase helper class in a content provider, however, that was not allowing me to reference the getString() method.  My solution so far is to do something like this:

```
private class MainDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    MainDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getString(R.string.createRoutesTable), null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL((getContext()).getString(R.string.createRoutesTable));
    }
}
```

Notice these two context references:

> **context**.getString()
>
> **(getContext())**.getString()

I don't know if this is the optimal long-term solution but it seems to work for the moment.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String s = getResources().getString(R.string.value);` also.

Comment: How to get access in some java class (not activity) such as viewPagerAdapter. I don't have there 'getContext'?