# R.string.value showing up as a number

Tags: android, date-format

For the below code I intended to get the system date and display it as per the formatting of the current locale, it's just that for the `R.string.date`. In emulator it always shows up as a long number (something like 821302314) instead of "Date: " which I has already externalized in the `string.xml`. Can anyone help to have a look why this is so?

```
final TextView mTimeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTimeText);

//get system date
Date date = new Date();
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText(R.string.date + " " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

#### layout.xml

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/mTimeText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:text="@string/date"
/>
```

#### strings.xml

```
<string name="date">Date:</string>
```

Comment: strings.xml:     <string name="date">Date:</string>

Comment: You should use getString(R.string.date) in place of R.string.date
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363245/r-string-value-help-android-notification

Answer (score 15):

`R.string.date` is indeed an `int`, you're missing the call to [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getText%28int%29) or `getString()`:

```
mTimeText.setText(getText(R.string.date) + " " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Even better, don't build the string in your code, but use a template with [`getString(int resId, Object... formatArgs)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
mTimeText.setText(getString(R.string.date, dateFormat.format(date)));
```

and in your `string.xml`:

```
<string name="date">Date: %s</string>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Philipp. I guess why a template is better is that it's not concatenating strings?

Comment: In this case it doesn't really make a difference, but depending on the language the sentence structure might be different (French is a prime candidate here :) ). Using a template saves you from doing string acrobatics in your code to support multiple languages.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you will get the ID of the String if you use R.string.date. 
As stated in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

> You can use either getString(int) or getText(int) to retrieve a string. getText(int) will retain any rich text styling applied to the string.

Example:

```
 this.getString(R.string.date);
```

Read about it here: [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29)

Answer (score 5):

To get string value from xml, you should call `this.getString(R.id.nameOfString)`. In your case this would be `mTimeText.setText(this.getString(R.string.date) + " " + dateFormat.format(date));`

Answer (score 0):

To override all *"R.string.*"* to *"getString(R.string.*)"* i wrote a little regex.

This regex also ignores the strings who already have a "getString" in front.

```
((?!getString\() R\.string\.[a-zA-Z1-9_]+)
```

You just have to press Strg+Shift+R in Android Studio to open the replace terminal and insert the regex above as "Find" and as "Replacement" the regex below.

```
 getString\( $1 \)
```

Don't forget to set "regular expression" checkbox.

For me this worked perfectly. But the "Find Regex" got one problem it only finds R.string when it starts with a whitespace. I don't know how to solve this because if i delete the whitespace ill find also the R.string that allready have the "getString".

May some can help to improve the regex or has a better way to achieve this.